# Interactive ePub3 issue: Need advice

Tags: ibooks, epub3

I have a technical doubt on an ePub3 job and thought of checking with you all and get your understanding and advise on it.

For one of my German client, I have created a ePub 3.0 re-flow with interactivity, we have used all the interactivities to work on pop-ups (Non-linear content) and it works well on iPad iBooks 3.2, as the initial request from client is to work only for iPad.

I understand that a latest Apple spec (iBooksAssetGuide 5.1 Rev 2) now says that “Develop scripts that perform well on both Mac OS and iOS devices: Interactivity on desktop computers requires input from a mouse while interactivity on iOS devices require touch input”. I’m not sure whether there would be any problem while this job goes into the Apple iBooksstore, due to the latest spec.

It would be of great help, if you all please share your idea’s / view to this problem.

Regards,
John.A

Answer (score 0):

Great question. With the latest version of OSX (Mavericks) running iBooks as well, there are a few things that need to be considered when using touch interactivity in ePub3 books. The most important (and relevant here) of these is making sure you are firing mouse events as well as touch events: because they behave differently.

The most robust solution that I have found to date is using JQuery or Quo's "tap" event: as it will fire with both touch and mouse events! However, if your code digs deeper (IE if you you use events like "touchstart", "touchmove", etc.) you will need to use the corresponding mouse events to insure functionality on the desktop.

Tap.js is a great little library for stuff like this: http://alxgbsn.co.uk/2012/03/12/tap-js-a-lightweight-tap-event-javascript-plugin/.

You should also be aware that iBooks for OSX behaves differently for many features (especially when it comes to external media content and dynamic loading of content), so you should never rely on OSX only when testing...

Good luck!